# How can I use smtpJS to add a self-generated PDF as a mail attachment?

Tags: javascript, smtp, jspdf, smtpjs

I can have a mail sent on my website with [smtpJS](https://www.smtpjs.com). But now I want to attach a newly generated PDF that was created with [jsPDF](https://parallax.typeform.com/to/phzpoR), I tried different things but it doesn't work for me. Does anyone recognize my problem?

I have added this link to WordPress in the functions.php file.

> ```
> wp_enqueue_script( 'pdfJS-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
> ```

But in my browser console always comes the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jsPDF
> (  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "A4");  )

My Code:

```
function sendMail() {

/* SmtpJS.com - v3.0.0 */
var Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t) { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText; null != t && t(e) }, a.send(n) }, ajax: function (e, n) { var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e); t.onload = function () { var e = t.responseText; null != n && n(e) }, t.send() }, createCORSRequest: function (e, n) { var t = new XMLHttpRequest; return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t } };

var receiverMail = document.getElementById('email').value;

var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "A4");          
var elementHandler = {
    '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
var source = window.document.getElementById("A4")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    297,
    210,
{
  'width': 210,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
});


var base64 = doc.output("datauristring");


Email.send({
    SecureToken : "C973D7AD-F097-4B95-91F4-40ABC5567812",
    To : receiverMail,
    From : "name@example.com",
    Subject : "Offerte von Name",
    Body : "tst",
    Attachments : [
        {
         name : "offerte.pdf",
         data : base64
   
        }]
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First I verified that `jsPDF` is loaded as a global variable if the script is on the page.  It is.  So your issue is that the script is not getting loaded to the page.  It's a PHP issue rather than a JS one.

The problem is the URL in your `wp_enqueue_script`.  You are loading a URL of a remote site so it is already a complete URL.  You do not need to add `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to it.  The code that you have here will look for the script on a URL like `https://mywordpresssite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js` which is obviously not the path that you want.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
   'pdfJS-js',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js', 
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '',
    true
);
```

You can just delete the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .`  and you should be fine.  I'm also adding in a version number as a best practice.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
   'pdfJS-js', // handle
   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js', // src
    array( 'jquery' ), // dependecies
    '1.3.2', // version
    true // in footer
);
```